# Java + XSLT performing slow when XML contains large number of lines

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Application is composing an XML structure and then processing it with an XSLT file which results in a transformed XML (in memory) suitable for a client. The problem is that while composing takes about less than a second (number of lines is about 10 000), transforming takes about 30 seconds.

Here is the java method:

```
StringWriter parsedOutStringWriter = new StringWriter();
StringWriter xmlStringWriter = new StringWriter();
File xsltFile = new File(xslFileProperties.getLocation() + xslFileForProcessing);

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(report, xmlStringWriter);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
transformer.setParameter("clientType", clientType);
transformer.setParameter("cardType", cardTypeValue);

Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStringWriter.getBuffer().toString()));
Result resultXmlWithFormat = new StreamResult(parsedOutStringWriter);
transformer.transform(source, resultXmlWithFormat);
```

This is the XML structure which results from jaxbMarshaller marshalling of Report.class (there are usually about 10000 `<transaction>` elements:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<report>
    <reportObject>
        <object>TEST</object>
        <objectValue>111111</objectValue>
    </reportObject>
    <reportContent>
        <reportInterval>
            <startDate>2014-07-01T00:00:00+03:00</startDate>
            <endDate>2016-09-30T23:59:59.999+03:00</endDate>
        </reportInterval>
        <client>
            <clientId>1111</clientId>
            <clientName>Some Client Name</clientName>
            <clientTown>-</clientTown>
            <clientAddress>-</clientAddress>
        </client>
        <transaction>
            <transactionId>1111111</transactionId>
            <transactionBatchId>2016091201111111</transactionBatchId>
            <transactionCode>1111111111111111</transactionCode>
            <transactionDate>2016-09-12T11:38:49+03:00</transactionDate>
            <transactionMain>111</transactionMain>
            <transactionAmount>199</transactionAmount>
            <transactionACode>      </transactionACode>
            <transactionBatch>111</transactionBatch>
            <transactionBatchDate>2016-09-12T11:40:27+03:00</transactionBatchDate>
            <transactionServiceFee>0</transactionServiceFee>
            <transactionType>1</transactionType>
            <transactionCType>AAAAA</transactionCType>
            <transactionCurrency>111</transactionCurrency>
            <transactionTerminal>11111111 111</transactionTerminal>
            <transactionTId>AA11111</transactionTId>
            <transactionClientId>111111</transactionClientId>
            <transactionClientName>SOME Client</transactionClientName>
            <transactionNetAmount>199</transactionNetAmount>
        </transaction>
    </reportContent>
</report>
```

This is the transforming XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>-->
    <xsl:decimal-format name="english" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />
    <xsl:param name="clientType" />
    <xsl:param name="cType" />
    <xsl:param name="Interval" />

    <xsl:template match="/report">

        <report>
            <reportObject>
                <object>
                    <xsl:value-of select="reportObject/object"/>
                </object>
                <objectValue>
                    <xsl:value-of select="reportObject/objectValue" />
                </objectValue>
            </reportObject>
            <reportContent>
                <client>
                    <clientId>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$clientType"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientId"/>
                    </clientId>
                    <clientName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientName" />
                    </clientName>
                    <clientTown>
                        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientTown" />
                        <xsl:if test="reportContent/client/clientTown = ''">-</xsl:if>
                    </clientTown>
                    <clientAddress>
                        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientAddress" />
                        <xsl:if test="reportContent/client/clientAddress = ''">-</xsl:if>
                    </clientAddress>
                </client>
                <reportInterval>
                    <startDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(reportContent/reportInterval/startDate, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
                    </startDate>
                    <endDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(reportContent/reportInterval/endDate, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
                    </endDate>
                </reportInterval>
                <cardTypes>
                    <cardType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cType"/>
                    </cardType>
                </cardTypes>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="reportContent/transaction" group-by="transactionBatchId">
                    <xsl:sort select="transactionClientName" />
                    <xsl:sort select="transactionBatchDate" />
                    <xsl:sort select="transactionBatch" />
                    <batch>
                        <batchDetails>
                            <batchId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="transactionBatchId"/>
                            </batchId>
                            <batchClientId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="transactionClientId"/>
                            </batchClientId>
                            <batchClientName>
                                <xsl:value-of select="transactionClientName"/>
                            </batchClientName>
                            <batchTransactionTerminal>
                                <xsl:value-of select="transactionTerminal"/>
                            </batchTransactionTerminal>
                            <batchNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="transactionBatch"/>
                            </batchNumber>
                            <batchDate>
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(transactionBatchDate,'[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
                            </batchDate>
                        </batchDetails>
                        <transactionList>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:sort select="transactionDate" />
                                <transaction>
                                    <transactionBatchId>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionBatchId"/>
                                    </transactionBatchId>
                                    <transactionCode>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionCode"/>
                                    </transactionCode>
                                    <transactionDate>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(transactionDate,'[D01].[M01].[Y0001] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]')" />
                                    </transactionDate>
                                    <transactionMain>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionMain" />
                                        <xsl:if test="transactionMain = ''">-</xsl:if>
                                    </transactionMain>
                                    <transactionACode>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionACode" />
                                        <xsl:if test="transactionACode = ''">-</xsl:if>
                                    </transactionACode>
                                    <transactionAmount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(transactionAmount div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')" />
                                    </transactionAmount>
                                    <transactionServiceFee>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(transactionServiceFee div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')" />
                                    </transactionServiceFee>
                                    <transactionNetAmount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(transactionNetAmount div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')" />
                                    </transactionNetAmount >
                                    <transactionCurrency>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionCurrency" />
                                        <xsl:if test="transactionCurrency = ''">-</xsl:if>
                                    </transactionCurrency>
                                    <transactionClientId>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionClientId" />
                                    </transactionClientId>
                                    <transactionBatch>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionBatch" />
                                    </transactionBatch>
                                    <transactionBatchDate>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(transactionBatchDate,'[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')" />
                                    </transactionBatchDate>
                                    <transactionType>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionType" />
                                    </transactionType>
                                    <transactionCType>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="transactionCType" />
                                    </transactionCType>
                                </transaction>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </transactionList>
                        <!-- batch total -->
                        <batchTotalItems>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()/transactionAmount)"/>
                        </batchTotalItems>
                        <batchTotalAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/transactionAmount) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                        </batchTotalAmount>
                        <batchTotalServiceFee>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/transactionServiceFee) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                        </batchTotalServiceFee>
                        <batchTotalNetAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/transactionNetAmount) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                        </batchTotalNetAmount>
                    </batch>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                <!-- overall total -->
                <totalItems>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(/report/reportContent/transaction/transactionAmount)"/>
                </totalItems>
                <totalAmount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/report/reportContent/transaction/transactionAmount) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                </totalAmount>
                <totalFee>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/report/reportContent/transaction/transactionServiceFee) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                </totalFee>
                <totalNetAmount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/report/reportContent/transaction/transactionNetAmount) div 100, '#,##0.00', 'english')"/>
                </totalNetAmount>
            </reportContent>
        </report>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is how the transformed XML looks like (there are usually about 10000 `<transaction>` elements and quite a few `<batch>` elements:

```
<report>
   <reportObject>
      <object>TEST</object>
      <objectValue>111111</objectValue>
   </reportObject>
   <reportContent>
      <client>
         <clientId type="">111</clientId>
         <clientName>Client Name</clientName>
         <clientTown>-</clientTown>
         <clientAddress>-</clientAddress>
      </client>
      <reportInterval>
         <startDate>01.07.2014</startDate>
         <endDate>30.09.2016</endDate>
      </reportInterval>
      <cardTypes>
         <cardType/>
      </cardTypes>
      <batch>
         <batchDetails>
            <batchId>2016091201111111</batchId>
            <batchClientId>1111111</batchClientId>
            <batchClientName>Some Client Name</batchClientName>
            <batchTransactionTerminal>11111111A11</batchTransactionTerminal>
            <batchNumber>89</batchNumber>
            <batchDate>14.04.2016</batchDate>
         </batchDetails>
         <transactionList>
            <transaction>
               <transactionBatchId>2016091201111111</transactionBatchId>
               <transactionCode>1111111111111111</transactionCode>
               <transactionDate>12.09.2016 09:33:52</transactionDate>
               <transactionMain>111</transactionMain>
               <transactionACode></transactionACode>
               <transactionAmount>1.99</transactionAmount>
               <transactionServiceFee>0.00</transactionServiceFee>
               <transactionNetAmount>1.99</transactionNetAmount>
               <transactionCurrency>111</transactionCurrency>
               <transactionClientId>1111111</transactionClientId>
               <transactionBatch>111</transactionBatch>
               <transactionBatchDate>14.04.2016</transactionBatchDate>
               <transactionType>1</transactionType>
               <transactionCType>AAAAA</transactionCType>
            </transaction>
         </transactionList>
       </batch>
    <reportContent>
</report>
```

Is there any way I can improve this XSLT performance wise? Or maybe the problem is in the java code? Note: template caching has been tested and doesn't help much.

Comment: Consider to add which version of Saxon exactly you use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sorry about that, Saxon-He: 9.7.0-8. I've tried the latest one which is -14 and that didn't change much.

Comment: Did you try running the transform from the command line to eliminate the possibility of the java code being the bottle neck? Also, did you try profiling (`-TP:profile.html` command line arg) like suggested in your previous question?

Comment: @DanielHaley The output file line count is about 190 000 - 200 000. If I run the transformation through console with -TP on my machine: Total time: 2046.902 milliseconds. If I run it on my machine through an id simulating the work of the above mentioned method it is: 3,2-3.7 seconds. I am trying to figure out if it is my java code that is doing this, but that is probably not the case, because all the other operations in code perform below 0.5 second level and just XSLT transformation takes a lot of time. Or this is something to do the production machine.

Comment: So on your machine Saxon from the command line needs only about 2 seconds and the Java code needs only between 3 and 4 seconds while on the production machine the transformation alone takes 30 seconds? Is there any mayor difference in processing power and/or memory between the two machines?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem has nothing to do with your XSLT code: it looks fine, and there is no way it should take this long; the fact that it runs in a respectable 2seconds on a different configuration confirms this. There's nothing obviously wrong with the Java code either. I would try and find out whether the CPU is busy for these 30 seconds, and if so where it is spending its time. Profiling the Java VM (e.g. using JVisualVM) might well yield insights. Check to see if there is thrashing for memory, or if there is any network traffic.

Comment: Another experiment that might yield insights is to measure how the performance varies as the file size (number of transactions) increases. Is the 30seconds a constant overhead, or is it a linear function of file size, or a quadratic function?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that the parameters being set from Java don't correlate with the parameters declared in the XSLT, and the parameters declared in the XSLT aren't actually used in the body of the stylesheet? This isn't going to be the cause of the performance problem, but it's a "code smell" that might be worth looking at.

Comment: @MichaelKay these parameters are vital. They are specifically populated and used for generating documents in different formats. There is no situation when these parameters are: empty or not used. Concerning memory: I think that is the only thing left to do. Otherwise I can't understand why all other operations are below second. Maybe Spring is somehow mixing badly with Saxon...? I don't know. The problem is that production machine is pretty "closed" and it is very difficult to try things out there. And my test environment doesn't reflect anything near production.

Comment: @MichaelKay actually what is more strange is that there is another transformation which uses a XSLT with very similar structure and which transforms the same incoming XML but produces an XML with about 2-3 times fewer lines. This transformation executes in 3 seconds on that very same production machine. I am thinking that maybe the 30 second transformation could be a anomaly related to maybe the JVM being busy with something else... In any case if you say that the XSLT and Java look fine, then I have to start looking into the JVM and how it performs. Thank you for your support!

Comment: It might be worth seeing if it makes any difference to reuse the same TransformerFactory for all transformations. I can't think of any immediate reason why this should solve the problem, but initialising a new TransformerFactory (and hence Saxon Configuration) for each transformation is an unnecessary cost.

Comment: @MichaelKay that is something I can try. But one thing bothers me very much. As I've stated before, there was a similar transformation done before (although with much fewer lines of output) and it was done in 3 seconds on that same production machine. I am more and more leaning towards the thought, that it was some kind of performance anomaly caused by something else kicking in on that machine. But I have to test and see. In any case thank you for your help.

Comment: Anomalies like that are clues to the solution, and clues should not bother you, they should encourage you. It should suggest experiments like doing the two transformations in a different order to see if it makes any difference.